# Conditionally preventing inserts from other concurrent transactions until the specific transaction finishes

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, locking, database-concurrency

I'm currently using Postgres 14 and have a problem related to concurrency control.

Let's say we have 2 transactions. Transaction A and transaction B. Transaction A acquires exclusive locks on multiple tables and transaction B has to wait until the transaction A releases the locks to be able to run insert queries into the locked tables. The transaction A finishes and transaction B successfully runs the insert queries.

The problem is that I only want to block other transactions from inserting conditionally.

To simplify the problem, let's say we have only 1 table in question and two of the previously mentioned transactions

| id | manufacturer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Volkswagen |
| 2 | Ferrari |

If the **Transaction A** is running, I want to prevent all inserts for **Transaction B** (and all possible concurrent transactions) that contain **Volkswagen** value for **manufacturer** column and allow all other inserts.

I was considering a solution with a trigger before insert. The idea was to use some kind of a lock that would relate to any kind of an identifier for the column in question and the value for that column based on which I would conditionally block all transactions that run insert queries until the running transaction has released the lock.

I was reading a bit about advisory locks but I don't have a good understanding of them yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a table which lists all manufacturers (just once each) and then have a rule that before anyone can insert into your shown table, they need to lock the corresponding row of the manufacturer table, like with `SELECT 1 from manufacturers WHERE manufacturer='Volkswagen' FOR UPDATE`